# How to Overwrite Spring Security Login Logout Files

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, logout

How can I overwrite default login logout pages of Spring Security. I will put my own login.html and logout.html files and don't use jsp files just works with static contents at  that side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify them in your `security-context.xml` (or whatever you've called yours) like this:

```
<form-login login-page="/login.htm" authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?login_error=1" default-target-url="/home/index.htm" />
```

But I think you'll find it difficult to write a login page that works with Spring Security and doesn't use JSP.

Here's an example JSP page you can start from: http://loianegroner.com/2010/01/spring-security-login-and-logout-form-jsp/